# ItemsWrapGrid Order in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following sample data setup in my XAML:

```
<vm:SoundModel.Animals>
  <vm:SoundGroup Title="Animals">
    <vm:SoundGroup.Items>
      <vm:SoundData Title="Animal 1" FilePath="Animal1.wav" />
      <vm:SoundData Title="Animal 2" FilePath="Animal2.wav" />
      <vm:SoundData Title="Animal 3" FilePath="Animal3.wav" />
    </vm:SoundGroup.Items>
  </vm:SoundGroup>
</vm:SoundModel.Animals>
```

And in my XAML I have the following:

```
<Page.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="SoundTileDataTemplate">
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="0, 0, 20, 20">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="150" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="0, 10, 10, 0">
        <Ellipse Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" StrokeThickness="3" />
        <Image Source="Assets/AppBar/play.png" />
      </Grid>

      <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="6, 0, 0, 6">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="30"  />
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Pivot x:Uid="Pvt">
  <PivotItem Header="{Binding Animals.Title}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Animals.Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SoundTileDataTemplate}">
      <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"  Orientation="Vertical"></ItemsWrapGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
  </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

The above gives me the following:

[image: listview boxes]

What code must I change so that it flows from left to right? So `Animal 3` should be on the bottom. I already tried setting `Orientation="Horizontal"` that gives me this:

[image: orientation different]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the orientation.

```
<ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"  Orientation="Horizontal"></ItemsWrapGrid>
```

[ItemsWrapGrid.Orientation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.orientation.aspx)

Comment: @Ciwan Pretty sure, I done this in the past.  I will take a look at it more when I'm off work, if someone else hasn't corrected me.  Maybe change the ListView's Vertical/Horizontal Alignment not to `Stretch`.

Comment: @Ciwan, I see what is going on now. Set  `Orientation="Horizontal"`, and reduce the size of your Item's width (in your ItemDataTemplate) to a smaller value until both columns appear.

Comment: ah good catch! thank you. Is there an easy way I can tell it to fill all available space and still have the two columns? Reducing width manually to 161 did it, but is there a better way than manual set (not very responsive this way)

Comment: @Ciwan There's a few topics about stretching the ItemsWrapGrid the way you want to.  I remember it being a pretty long answer, so I can't type it here.  Just search SO for it, it's been asked a few times.